# Math Function For Getting An Increasing/Decreasing Percentage

Tags: math

Is there a function or set of functions in php that will help me solve line 1 of this problem:

```
Noofdays factorial (for 5days) = 5+4+3+2+1
BasicValue = 200/ 15 =13.3
DailyDosage= Daynumber x basicValue
```

Decreasing dosage for 200 milligram prescription  example: Day1 - 67, Day2 - 53, Day 3 - 40,Day 4 - 27, Day 5 - 13

Where `200` Needs to be a variable and `NoofDays` needs to be a variable.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. Also it's probably not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

*1+2+...+n = n⋅(n+1)/2*, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

factorial would be 5*4*3*2*1 = 120, not (sum) 5+4+3+2+1 = 15.

```
$Noofdays = 5;
$totalAmount = 200;

$dayThreeAmount = calculateDosage(3, $Noofdays, $totalAmount);

function calculateDosage($day, $totalDays, $totalAmount)
{
   return ($totalAmount / ($totalDays * ($totalDays+1) / 2)) * ($totalDays - $day + 1);
}
```

I'm assuming sum is what you wanted...

EDIT: Doh, divide not multiply...

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about what you are having problems with here. But the below seems to do what you want.

```
$currentDay = 4;
$noOfDays = 5;
$milligram = 200;
$basicValue = $milligram / array_sum(range($noOfDays, 1,-1));
$dailyDosage = round($currentDay * $basicValue);
```

Comment: Danny, this is correct. The results (dailyDosage) are backwards, but I see how to get the basicValue now, which was giving me a hard time.